# How to give case when statment value in SQL Server's From part

Tags: sql-server

can someone tell me how I can make this case when statement work in the From part? It seems like I can't set value for FB3.Liquidityscore. Thanks for your help!

```
   left join [RISK].[dbo].[FILiquidityBuckets] FB3
    on FB3.Metric='Effective term ' and
    CASE 
           WHEN CAST(sa.effectiveTerm AS INT) BETWEEN 0 and 2 THEN FB3.LiquidityScore=1
           WHEN CAST(sa.effectiveTerm AS INT) BETWEEN 2 and 10 THEN FB3.LiquidityScore=2
           WHEN CAST(sa.effectiveTerm AS INT) >10 THEN FB3.LiquidityScore=4
           END
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to update the value of `FB3.Liquidity Score`? Or are you trying to compare it as another part of the `join` condition, if the other ones are true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply rephrase the `CASE` expression using plain logic, e.g.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN [RISK].[dbo].[FILiquidityBuckets] FB3
    ON FB3.Metric = 'Effective term ' AND (
        (CAST(sa.effectiveTerm AS INT) BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND
         FB3.LiquidityScore = 1) OR
        (CAST(sa.effectiveTerm AS INT) BETWEEN 2 AND 10 AND
         FB3.LiquidityScore = 2) OR
        (CAST(sa.effectiveTerm AS INT) > 10 AND FB3.LiquidityScore = 4)
    )
```